# Assign dynamic SQL Query result to a variable and then use variable to in UPDATE TABLE

Tags: t-sql

Application: MS SSMS version: 18.12.1
Windows 10

I have **Table_Name1** that contains the below info

| col1Name | col2Name | col3Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -,99 | fred | 1,23 |

col1 - col2 - col3 are all string datatype

col1 ordinal value = 1
col2 ordinal value = 2
col3 ordinal value = 3

I used the below code to retrieve the columns names from TABLE_NAME1 that were related to monetary values and placed those columns into TABLE_NAME2

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STAGE.DBO.TABLE_NAME2<BR>
SELECT SC.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME<BR>
,SC.COLORDER AS COLUMN_ORDINAL<BR>
,CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SMALLINT) AS ROW_NUM<BR>
INTO STAGE.DBO.TABLE_NAME2<BR>
FROM SYSOBJECTS AS SO<BR>
INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS AS SC ON SO.ID = SC.ID<BR>
WHERE SO.XTYPE = 'U'<BR>
AND SO.NAME = 'TABLE_NAME2'<BR>
AND SC.COLORDER IN (1,3)<BR>
ORDER BY SC.COLORDER, SC.NAME<BR>
```

**TABLE_NAME2** contains the following info

| column_name | column_ordinal | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1Name | 1 | 1 |
| col2Name | 3 | 2 |

**What I want to do:** loop through TABLE_NAME1 column names and if there is a match with a value in TABLE_NAME2, then return that column name and assign it to a variable. Use the variable in an UPDATE TABLE statement to replace the comma (,) with a dot (.)

**Below is what i tried:** to have the result assigned to a variable

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLQRY1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LOOP1 SMALLINT
DECLARE @TABLE_ROW_COUNT1 SMALLINT
DECLARE @XTYPE1 CHAR(1)
DECLARE @COL_NAME1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TABLE_NAME1 = 'CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG'
SET @TABLE_NAME2 = 'STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HH_ACT_COL_NAME_STG'
SET @LOOP1 = 1
SET @XTYPE1 = 'U'
SET @TABLE_ROW_COUNT1 =2

WHILE @LOOP1 <= @TABLE_ROW_COUNT1
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQRY1 = N'SELECT @COL_NAME1=TBL2.COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM ( SELECT SC.[NAME] AS COL_NAME, SC.COLORDER AS COL_ORDER
                               FROM SYSOBJECTS AS SO
                               INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS AS SC ON SO.ID = SC.ID
                               WHERE SO.XTYPE = '''+ @XTYPE1 +''' 
                               AND SO.NAME = '''+ @TABLE_NAME1 +'''
                               ) AS TBL1
                        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
                                     FROM '+ @TABLE_NAME2 +'
                               ) AS TBL2 ON TBL2.COLUMN_NAME = TBL1.COL_NAME
                               AND TBL2.COLUMN_ORDINAL = TBL1.COL_ORDER
                        WHERE TBL2.ROW_NUM = ' + CAST(@LOOP1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

    EXECUTE @COL_NAME1 = sp_executesql @SQLQRY1 OUTPUT


    PRINT 'COL_NAME = '+ CAST(@COL_NAME1 AS VARCHAR);
    PRINT 'LOOP NUMBER = '+ CAST(@LOOP1 AS VARCHAR);


    /* INCREMENT */
    SET @LOOP1 = @LOOP1 + 1
END
```

Thank you all for your support as I am new to T-SQL

Comment: Have a look at:  https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql ,  see section 2.1 sp_executesql .

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the documentation. It helped alot.  Just wanted to post most solution.

STEP1: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE THAT WILL CONTIAN THE NAME OF THE COLUMNS THAT ARE SUPPOSE TO HAVE NUMERIC DATA

```
USE [STAGE]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_COLUMN_NAME_STG
SELECT SC.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
,SC.COLORDER AS COLUMN_ORDINAL
,CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SMALLINT) AS ROW_NUM
INTO STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_COLUMN_NAME_STG
FROM SYSOBJECTS AS SO
INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS AS SC ON SO.ID = SC.ID
WHERE SO.XTYPE = 'U' 
AND SO.NAME = 'CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG'
AND SC.COLORDER IN (26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,39,40,45,46,47,48,49,50,54,55,56,59,60,61,64,65,66,83,84)
ORDER BY SC.COLORDER, SC.NAME
```

STEP2: APPLY GLOBAL SCRUBBING LOGIC TO THE COLUMNS CONTIAN NUMERIC DATA

```
USE [STAGE]
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLQRY1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LOOP1 SMALLINT
DECLARE @TABLE_ROW_COUNT1 SMALLINT
DECLARE @XTYPE1 CHAR(1)
DECLARE @COL_NAME1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TABLE_NAME1 = 'CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG'
SET @TABLE_NAME2 = 'STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_COLUMN_NAME_STG'
SET @LOOP1 = 1
SET @XTYPE1 = 'U'
SET @TABLE_ROW_COUNT1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_COLUMN_NAME_STG)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SELECT @ParmDefinition =  N'@COL_NAME1  NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT';


WHILE @LOOP1 <= @TABLE_ROW_COUNT1
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQRY1 = N'SELECT @COL_NAME1=TBL2.COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM ( SELECT SC.[NAME] AS COL_NAME, SC.COLORDER AS COL_ORDER
                               FROM SYSOBJECTS AS SO
                               INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS AS SC ON SO.ID = SC.ID
                               WHERE SO.XTYPE = '''+ @XTYPE1 +''' 
                               AND SO.NAME = '''+ @TABLE_NAME1 +'''
                               ) AS TBL1
                        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
                                     FROM '+ @TABLE_NAME2 +'
                               ) AS TBL2 ON TBL2.COLUMN_NAME = TBL1.COL_NAME
                               AND TBL2.COLUMN_ORDINAL = TBL1.COL_ORDER
                        WHERE TBL2.ROW_NUM = ' + CAST(@LOOP1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQRY1, @ParmDefinition, @COL_NAME1 OUTPUT

    PRINT 'COL_NAME = '+ CAST(@COL_NAME1 AS VARCHAR);
    PRINT 'LOOP NUMBER = '+ CAST(@LOOP1 AS VARCHAR);

    
    /* REMOVE ALL LEADING AND TRAILING SPACES */
    UPDATE STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG
    SET @COL_NAME1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(@COL_NAME1))

    /* REMOVE ALL ASCII CHAR (13) PRESS ENTER */
    UPDATE STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG
    SET @COL_NAME1 = REPLACE(@COL_NAME1,CHAR(13),'')

    /* REMOVE ALL ASCII CHAR (10) LINE FEED  */
    UPDATE STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG 
    SET @COL_NAME1 = REPLACE(@COL_NAME1,CHAR(10),'')

    /* REMOVE ALL ASCII CHAR (9) HORIZONTAL TAB  */
    UPDATE STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG 
    SET @COL_NAME1 = REPLACE(@COL_NAME1,CHAR(9),'')

    /* REMOVE ALL LEADING AND TRAILING SPACES - 2ND PASS */
    UPDATE STAGE.DBO.CH_IBRO_HOUSEHOLD_ACTIVITY_STG 
    SET @COL_NAME1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(@COL_NAME1))

    /* INCREMENT */
    SET @LOOP1 = @LOOP1 + 1
END
```